# Java - Using Several Completion Stage to form one response json

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

Im not sure if Im going the right way but currently im stuck.
What i wanted to achieve is that I want to get a list of items according to it's parent category.

`ParentCategory --< Category --< Item`

And not that familiar yet with the CompletionStage.

So here I have 2 queries. First query is getting the list of ParentCategory. I will then iterate through that list to get a list of items per ParentCategory

```
    ParentCategoryDao {
        findParentCategoriesByShop(int shopId);
    }

    ItemDao {
        //joined query of item and child category
        findItemByChildCategory(final int parentCategoryId)

    }
```

In controller:

```
    public CompletionStage<List<ProcessClass>> retrieveItems(final int shopId) {


        parentCategoryDao.findParentCategoriesByShop(shopId).thenApplyAsync(parentCategoryStream ->{

            ParentCategoryJson parentCategoryJson = new ParentCategoryJson();

            for(ParentCategory parentCategory : parentCategoryStream.collect(Collectors.toList())) {

                processClassJson.setProcessClassId(parentCategory.getId());
                processClassJson.setProcessClassName(processClass.getProcessClass());

                itemDao.findItemByChildCategory(parentCategory.getId()).thenApplyAsync(itemStream ->{
                    // Do operations on forming a list of items

                }, ec.current());


                //then maybe after is something like
                processClassJson.setItemList(itemList);

            }


        },ec.current())

    }
```

By the way, I'm using Play Framework. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The declarations of your DAO interfaces are incomplete (missing return type), and you are using the undeclared `ProcessClass` type and `processClass`, `processClassJson` and `itemList` variables. What are you having an issue with in the end? What have you tried and why does it not work?

Comment: Everything in there is just for illustration purposes.

Comment: That's fine but you should make it a [mcve] and clearly indicate what is your problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

Surprising to see you are not returning anything in thenApplyAsync block. Also, non-blocking functions should be called only from thenCompose to avoid nested CompletionStage. Anyways, below is the code which should solve your problem.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

....

  public static CompletionStage<List<Object>> retrieveItems(final int shopId) {
    return parentCategoryDao
        .findParentCategoriesByShop(shopId)
        .thenComposeAsync(
            stream ->
                resultsOfAllFutures(
                    stream
                        .map(
                            parentCategory ->
                                itemDao
                                    .findItemByChildCategory(parentCategory.getId())
                                    .thenApplyAsync(
                                        itemStream -> {
                                          // Do operations on forming a list of items
                                          return null;
                                        }))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())));
  }

      public static <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> resultsOfAllFutures(
          List<CompletionStage<T>> completionStages) {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null)
            .thenApply(
                __ ->
                    completionStages
                        .stream()
                        .map(future -> future.toCompletableFuture().join())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
      }
```